# Modbus protocol escapes the thread (Android,Jamod)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, tcp, modbus

I'm trying to connect to PLC using ModBus protocol. I'm calling ModBus connect method from thread and I'm  getting exception that I'm running communications on the main thread...
I wonder where it escapes...

Exception:

```
    08-02 10:48:44.461: W/System.err(4395): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    08-02 10:48:44.471: W/System.err(4395):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
    08-02 10:48:44.471: W/System.err(4395):     at
```

Code:

```
    package com.kikudjiro.android.echo;

    import net.wimpi.modbus.facade.ModbusTCPMaster;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class settings extends Activity implements Runnable {

        Button connect_b, disconnect_b;
        Thread comm = new Thread(this);

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.settings);
            addListenerOnButton();
        }

        public void addListenerOnButton() {

            connect_b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            disconnect_b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            connect_b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    comm.run();
                }

            });

            disconnect_b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    comm.interrupt();
                }

            });
        }

        // @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                ModbusTCPMaster MB = new ModbusTCPMaster("192.168.107.29", 502);
                //while (!comm.interrupted()) {
                    Log.i("!!!!!!!", "try!");
                    MB.connect();
                    MB.writeCoil(1, 1, true);
                    MB.disconnect();
                //}
            }

            catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("hhh", "exceptionas!!!");
            } finally {
                Log.i("!!!!!!!", "finally!");
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On button click, you call `comm.run()` which just executes the `run()` method directly in the context of the UI thread. This is a common error, you should never call `run()` directly on a `Thread` instance. Use `comm.start()` to execute the Modbus code in the context of your worker thread.

[Here is the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29)