# Modbus tcp android application

Tags: android, eclipse, tcp, modbus

i am developing android application to control plc with help of tcp/ip modbus anyone has good tutorial on that?
[Modbus protocol escapes the thread (Android,Jamod)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773864/modbus-protocol-escapes-the-thread-android-jamod)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Modbus on Android** can be seen **[here](http://www.nyx.net/~ddileo/)**, **ModbusDroid** with source can be found **[here](http://www.bencatlin.com/sofware-projects/modbus-droid/)**, and **modbus4j** can be found **[here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/modbus4j/files/modbus4j/)**.

Comment: hi i am new in this type of programming. i am trying to read holding registers using modbusj4 but its not working can you help me? i am using these line- `System.out.println(getValue(modbReadLocator)); ModbusResponse response = (ReadResponse)send(request); new ReadInputRegistersRequest(slaveId, readoffset,1 )`

Answer (score 1):

I have done what you are trying to do. I posted a question and the answer for my problem in the [following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560429/sending-a-boolean-value-to-a-plc-from-android). I hope this one helps a bit.

Comment: i visited it. hi i am new in this type of programming. i am trying to read holding registers using modbusj4 but its not working can you help me?
i am using these line-
`System.out.println(getValue(modbReadLocator));
 ModbusResponse response = (ReadResponse)send(request);
new ReadInputRegistersRequest(slaveId, readoffset,1 )`