# Sending a boolean value to a PLC from Android

Tags: java, android, boolean, plc, modbus

I was able to make a connection with a PLC to read data from it. Now there's one problem and it is that I have to write a method to modify the data from the PLC. To achieve this, I have to send two values to the PLC: an int value and a boolean value. I got the int value solved via the classes from the net.wimpi.modbus package. But when it comes to the boolean value I have no clue what to do.

If someone had the same problem as I do now, could you please send me a reference where I can find a solution or a link of a really good tutorial to solve my problem? Someone posted a couple of links in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490661/modbus-tcp-andriod-application) but it sends me to tutorials that doesn't have much to do with the communication with the PLC's and how to treat the data of the PLC.

**EDIT**

I made the connection with a Modicon M340 PLC, and for the connection I use the classes of the net.wimpi.modbus package. I made the connection in my code through the classes `ModbusTCPTransaction` and `TCPMasterConnection`, and I read the values through the classes `ReadMultipleRegistersRequest` and `ReadMultipleRegistersResponse`.

The code I made for the connection:

```
    private InetAddress m_Address;
private ModbusTCPTransaction m_Transaction = null;
private TCPMasterConnection m_Connection = null;

int port = Modbus.DEFAULT_PORT;
private Activity activity;


public ModbusConnection(Activity activity, String ip)
{
    this.activity = activity;

    try {
        m_Address = InetAddress.getByName(ip); 
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } // the slave'saddress
}

public void getTransaction(InetAddress inet) throws Exception
{
    /*Variables for the reading of the PLC data*/
    int port = Modbus.DEFAULT_PORT;

    /*Data initialization for the reading of the PLC data*/
    m_Connection = new TCPMasterConnection(inet);
    m_Connection.setPort(port);
    m_Connection.connect();
    m_Transaction = new ModbusTCPTransaction(m_Connection);
}
```

And to read the values, I call the next code all the time. I accomplished only reading and writing int, String and float values through words that I read from an offset declared on the PLC:

```
    private ReadMultipleRegistersResponse readValues(int offset, int count) 
{
    ReadMultipleRegistersRequest rReq = null; // the request
    ReadMultipleRegistersResponse rRes = null; // the response

    try {

        rReq = new ReadMultipleRegistersRequest(offset, count);
        m_Transaction.setRequest(rReq);
        m_Transaction.execute();
        rRes = (ReadMultipleRegistersResponse) m_Transaction.getResponse();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("AsyncTask", "doInBackground: Exception");
    }
    return rRes;    
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I think I accomplished what I wanted. There are 4 classes that I use to read the coils:

`ReadCoilsRequest`
`ReadCoilsResponse`
`WriteMultipleCoilsRequest`
`WriteMultileCoilsResponse`

What I did is two methods to read and write coils into the PLC:

```
    private ReadCoilsResponse readBytes(int offset, int count) 
{
    ReadCoilsRequest rReq = null; // the request
    ReadCoilsResponse rRes = null; // the response

    try {

        rReq = new ReadCoilsRequest(offset, count);
        m_Transaction.setRequest(rReq);
        m_Transaction.execute();
        rRes = (ReadCoilsResponse) m_Transaction.getResponse();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("AsyncTask", "doInBackground: Exception");
    }
    return rRes;    
}

    public void writeBytes(int wordNumber, BitVector b) {
    try {               
        WriteMultipleCoilsRequest wReq = null; //
        WriteMultipleCoilsResponse wRes = null; //

        wReq = new WriteMultipleCoilsRequest(211, b);
        m_Transaction.setRequest(wReq);
        m_Transaction.execute();    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("AsyncTask", "doInBackground: Exception");
    }
}
```

Also, I made a method to read BitVector variables using the Coils classes:

```
    public BitVector readBitVector(int offset, int count) 
{
    BitVector myBitVector;  

    ReadCoilsResponse rRes = readBytes(offset, count);
    rRes = (ReadCoilsResponse) m_Transaction.getResponse();
    myBitVector = rRes.getCoils();

    return myBitVector; 
}
```

After this, what I used to set the bit to 1 or 0 is using a native function from the BitVector class from the net.wimpi.modbus.util package in my code:

```
test.setBit(2, true);
```

NOTE: It is important to remember that everytime that you want to read or write values to the plc, the best way to do it is opening a closing the connection to the PLC.

Comment: Hint: you can just leave "Problems with" from the title of your questions on SO. If you post it here, it's implied that there are some problems that need solving.

Comment: Can you tell us, what you have tried already. And what PLC is it? How did you make the connection? This might influence the way to handle booleans.

Comment: @Fildor I just edited my question and answered the questions you asked me

Comment: I found an answer through [this link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jamod/forums/forum/159114/topic/4048643), I'm checking still how to do it, but if someone has a easier way I will appreciate it!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My definitive answer is: you have to treat the registers as bits. So if you want to write the second bit of a register represented in an int value in your code, you will have to do something like this:

```
intValue = m_Data[1].getValue();
intValue = intValue | 2;
m_Data[1].setValue(intValue);
```

The second line modifies the bit I want to write in my PLC.